# Read multiple CSV an each column has its CSV name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, glob

to sum up i need that each colum as the name that the csv file has.

This is what I have done so far :

```
path = r'C:\Users\dfgdfsgsfg\Untitled Folder\tickers' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f , parse_dates=True, index_col="date") for f in all_files)

concat = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)

df = concat['PriceUSD']

df.columns = [ ??????? ] #what do I put in here?
```

[This what I get when I dont name the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIp4Z.png)

Comment: Try this line in your code and see if it works. df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f , parse_dates=True, index_col="date")
                             .assign(filename = f)
                             for f in all_files)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a table made up of the values in the `'PriceUSD'` column of a bunch of CSVs, and have the columns each named from the CSV it came from?  Wouldn't you just do `df.columns = all_files`?

Comment: @sammywemmy nop, doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 66 elements, new values have 68 elements

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas that error means there are 68 csv files but after concat there are only 66 columns, which means that 2 CSVs don't have a column `PriceUSD`.  If all your files have the column you are interested in that line would probably work.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

i also tryied this , but not quiet the results i wished

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f , parse_dates=True, index_col="date").assign(filename = f) for f in all_files)

concat = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1)

df = concat['PriceUSD']

df.columns = all_files[:-2]

df
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODrjy.png)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thanks for the help ! I imported the ''PriceUSD'' colum from different CSV files. instead of the columns saying ''PriceUSD'' I want them to have the name of the CSV file that they imported from

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in only the single column from all those CSV files, then while parsing the csv just trim it to just the column you want:

```
def getPriceUSD(filename):
    """reads csv file then returns dataframe with just the column 'PriceUSD'
    with the filename as the column title"""
    data = pd.read_csv(f , parse_dates=True, index_col="date")
    data = data["PriceUSD"]
    data.columns = [filename]
    return data
```

Then concat all the already parsed and formatted columns together:

```
df = pd.concat(map(getPriceUSD, all_files), axis=1)
```

And before you ask, if you don't want the full path then use `os.path.basename(filename)` for the column instead of just `filename`